# Fourier transform in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I try to show that
$$
 \int\limits_{R^3} \frac{e^{i\xi x} d\xi}{\xi^2 - k^2 - i0} = e^{ikx} \int\limits_{R^3} \frac{e^{i\xi x}d\xi}{\xi^2 + 2(k + i0\frac{k}{|k|})\xi}, \;\;\; k,x \in \mathbb R^3
$$
I tried to make the change $\xi \mapsto \xi + k$ in second integral. I obtained
$$
 \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \; \int\limits_{\mathbb R^d} \frac{e^{i\xi x} d\xi}{(\xi + i\epsilon \frac{k}{|k|})^2 - k^2 + \epsilon^2 - 2i|k|\epsilon}
$$
So I don't know what to do...

Comment: Why write out $i0$?  Isn't that just zero?

Comment: $\xi^2-k^2 - i 0$ is a way of saying that you consider $\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \frac{e^{i\xi x} }{\xi^2 - k^2 - i \epsilon} \mathrm{d} \xi$.

Comment: foil the square in the denominator ;)

Answer (score 2):

Stuff does work out in spherical coordinates. Let $\kappa >0 $ be such that $\kappa^2 = k^2$. Align north pole of spherical $\xi$-coordinates along $x$ vector. Let $\vert x \vert = \rho$. Then $ \xi \cdot x = r \rho \cos(\theta)$, and $\mathrm{d} \xi = r^2 \sin \theta \mathrm{d} r \mathrm{d} \theta \mathrm{d} \phi$:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{i\xi x} }{\xi^2 - k^2 - i \epsilon} \mathrm{d} \xi &=& 
  \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0}  \int_0^{2 \pi} \mathrm{d} \phi \int_0^\infty r^2 \mathrm{d} r \int_0^\pi \mathrm{d} \theta \, \sin(\theta) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{e}^{i r \rho \cos \theta} }{r^2 - \kappa^2 - i \epsilon} \\
  &=& \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \left( 2 \pi  \int_0^\infty r^2 \mathrm{d} r \frac{1}{r^2 - \kappa^2 - i \epsilon} \cdot \frac{2 \sin(r \rho)}{r \rho} \right)  \\
 &=& \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \left( 2 \pi  \int_0^\infty r^2 \mathrm{d} r \frac{1}{r^2 - \kappa^2 - i \epsilon} \cdot \frac{2 \sin(r \rho)}{r \rho} \right) \\
 &=& \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \left( \frac{2 \pi^2}{\rho} \mathrm{e}^{i \rho \sqrt{\kappa^2 + i \epsilon}} \right) = \frac{2 \pi^2}{\rho} \mathrm{e}^{i \kappa \rho}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The integral with respect to $r$ was carried out my method of residues.

Comment: thank you, but integral on the left I can compute too)

Comment: @Nimza I am not understanding your comment. If this post not-helpful, or have you figured out a different way to compute the integral ?

Comment: Rather it is not helpful because I wanted to show that integrals on the left and on the right are equal. I don't need to count integral on the left

Comment: @Nimza Sorry, I missed your question, then. Notice that with formal substitution $\xi \to \xi + k + n \sqrt{\epsilon} \mathrm{e}^{i \pi/4}$, where $\vert n \vert =1$, the denominator on the l.h.s. becomes $ \xi^2 + 2 \xi \cdot \left( k + n \sqrt{\epsilon} \mathrm{e}^{i \pi/4} \right) + 2 k \cdot n \sqrt{\epsilon} \mathrm{e}^{i \pi/4}$. Now you should figure out why $n = \frac{k}{\vert k \vert}$ is a good choice.

Comment: But we leave $R^3$ making this substitution

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{{\mathbb R}^{3}}{\expo{i\vec{\xi}\cdot\vec{x}}
                       \over \xi^{2} - k^{2} - \ic 0^{+}}\,d^{3}\vec{\xi}}$

> Note that $\ds{\pars{\verts{k} + \ic 0^{+}}^{2} = k^{2} + \ic 0^{+}}$ such that
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{{\mathbb R}^{3}}{\expo{i\vec{\xi}\cdot\vec{x}}
>                        \over \xi^{2} - k^{2} - \ic 0^{+}}\,d^{3}\vec{\xi}}
> =\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd\xi\,
> {4\pi\xi^{2} \over \xi^{2} - \pars{\verts{k} + \ic 0^{+}}^{2}}\
> \overbrace{\int\expo{i\vec{\xi}\cdot\vec{x}}\,{\dd\Omega_{\vec{\xi}} \over 4\pi}}
> ^{\ds{\sin\pars{\xi x} \over \xi x}}
> \\[3mm]&=2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> {\bracks{\xi^{2}  - \pars{\verts{k} + \ic 0^{+}}^{2}}
>  + \pars{\verts{k} + \ic 0^{+}}^{2}\over \xi^{2} - \pars{\verts{k} + \ic 0^{+}}^{2}}
> \,{\sin\pars{x\xi} \over x\xi}\,\dd\xi
> \\[3mm]&={2\pi^{2} \over x} + 2\pi k^{2}\color{#00f}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> {1 \over \xi^{2} - \pars{\verts{k} + \ic 0^{+}}^{2}}
> \,{\sin\pars{x\xi} \over x\xi}\,\dd\xi}\tag{1} 
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&\color{#00f}{%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{1 \over \xi^{2} - \pars{\verts{k} + \ic 0^{+}}^{2}}
\,{\sin\pars{x\xi} \over x\xi}\,\dd\xi}
=\Im\,\pp\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{1 \over \xi^{2} - \pars{\verts{k} + \ic 0^{+}}^{2}}
\,{\expo{\ic x\xi} \over x\xi}\,\dd\xi
\\[3mm]&=\Im\bracks{%
2\pi\ic\,{1 \over 2\pars{\verts{k} + \ic 0^{+}}}\,
{\exp\pars{\ic x\pars{\verts{k} + \ic 0^{+}}} \over x\pars{\verts{k} + \ic 0^{+}}}
-\int_{\pi}^{0}{1 \over -\pars{\verts{k} + \ic 0^{+}}^{2}}\,{\ic \over x}\,\dd\theta}
\\[3mm]&={\pi \over x}\,
\Re\pars{\expo{\ic\verts{k}x} \over \bracks{\verts{k} + \ic 0^{+}}^{2}}
-{\pi \over x}\,\Re\pars{1 \over \bracks{\verts{k} + \ic 0^{+}}^{2}}
=\color{#00f}{{\pi \over xk^{2}}\bracks{\cos\pars{\verts{k}x} - 1}}
\end{align}

> Now, we'll replace this result in expression $\pars{1}$:
>   $$
> \color{#00f}{\large%
> \int_{{\mathbb R}^{3}}{\expo{i\vec{\xi}\cdot\vec{x}}
>                        \over \xi^{2} - k^{2} - \ic 0^{+}}\,d^{3}\vec{\xi}
> =2\pi^{2}\,{\cos\pars{\verts{k}x} \over x}}\,,\qquad\quad x = \verts{\vec{x}}
> $$